# What does "#! -*-perl-*-" mean?

Tags: shell, perl, shebang

In the perl documents one can read:

> Parsing of the #! switches starts wherever "perl" is mentioned in the
>   line. The sequences "-*" and "- " are specifically ignored so that you
>   could, if you were so inclined, say
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> #! -*-perl-*-
> eval 'exec perl -x -wS $0 ${1+"$@"}'
>     if 0; to let Perl see the -p switch.
> ```
>
> to let Perl see the -p switch.

I'm confused about the comment. The line "-*-perl-*-" is inside a comment, and shebang has already been parsed. If I write:

```
!/bin/sh
#! -*-python-*-
print 1
```

It doesn't work. Also, those sequences are always ignored? Does it mean that that is something similar to '/bin/sh -perl'? That fails on the terminal.

Then it also mentions the "-p" switch. But there is no p switch in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your quote is incompletely copied. The text actually says

> Parsing of the `#!` switches starts wherever "perl" is mentioned in
>   the line. 
>   The sequences `-*` and `-` are specifically ignored so that you could,
>   if you were so inclined, say
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh --
> #! -*- perl -*- -p
> eval 'exec perl $0 -S ${1+"$@"}'
>     if 0;
> ```
>
> to let Perl see the `-p` switch.

There are three things at play here.

- The `#!/bin/sh` shebang causes the script to be run by `sh`.  The `eval 'exec ...'` stuff is a hack to force `sh` to `exec perl` if that happens.
- The `-*- perl -*-` specifier is an Emacs [mode string](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html). But it also coincidentally triggers the next behavior.
- The second `#!` together with the `perl` text from the previous item are what trigger the described option parsing. As per the parsing rules, the mode string is ignored, and the `-p` at the end of that line gets picked up as the actual option for Perl.

The preceding paragraphs in the documentation should perhaps also be quoted for context:

> As of Perl 5, the `#!` line is always examined for switches
>   as the line is being parsed.
>   Thus, if you're on a machine that only allows one argument with
>   the `#!` line, or worse, doesn't even recognize the `#!` line,
>   you still can get consistent switch behavior regardless of
>   how Perl was invoked, even if `-x` was used to
>   find the beginning of the script.
>
> Because many operating systems silently chop off kernel interpretation
>   of the `#!` line after 32 characters, some switches may be passed in
>   on the command line, and some may not; you could even get a `-` without
>   its letter, if you're not careful. You probably want to make sure that
>   all your switches fall either before or after that 32 character
>   boundary. Most switches don't actually care if they're processed
>   redundantly, but getting a `-` instead of a complete switch could
>   cause Perl to try to execute standard input instead of your script.
>   And a partial `-I` switch could also cause odd results.

... And later on:

> If the `#!` line does not contain the word "perl", the program named
>   after the `#!` is executed instead of the Perl interpreter. This is
>   slightly bizarre, but it helps people on machines that don't do `#!`,
>   because they can tell a program that their `SHELL` is `/usr/bin/perl`,
>   and Perl will then dispatch the program to the correct interpreter
>   for them.

Comment: Does your version of Perl documentation really contain the `-p`? It was removed in [2004](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/commit/428bacd701ef45155f9dfd0d9c3d063dc305de00).

Comment: Oh, I just googled `perlrun`. I have already closed the tab but IIRC the page was on `perl.com`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the long answer. I doubt that I grasp everything. So the script is expected to be executed with perl. If it is not, then it will be executed with sh. This will execute third line which will make perl execute the same file. Now. the second line will be interpreted by perl and it is **not** a shebang. Following some perl parsing logic it will pick the flag p (which was missing from the documentation as the other answer mentioned). Is that it?

Not super sure what role the Emacs mode string plays here though.

Comment: Yeah, the `sh` detour is a way to get consistent behavior across platforms. Ignoring the mode line is a convenience for any Emacs users. Vaguely like the `exec` snippet is valid (but has different semantics) in `sh` and Perl, allowing the mode line to also trigger Perl's option parsing logic at the same time is just a hack to reduce the amount of boilerplate you need at the start of a script.

Comment: Perhaps it should be said that this was useful before Linux and Windows became viable platforms, back when $gender was $gender and there was only one kind of Coca-Cola.

Comment: I think the original text was created by some "hack" where the author didn't know exactly what the (suspected original second line) was about. Because the Emacs docs say in [23.3 Choosing File Modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs///manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html): " the simplest is to put the mode name in the first nonblank line, preceded and followed by `-\*-'." But the line *is not the first nonblank line!*

Answer (score 2):

It's an error in the documentation. The original line in the script was

```
# -*- perl -*- -p
```

See [this pull request](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/pull/17532).